# Excel VBA code works for me but not others

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have some code that does a number of things and all works fine for me, but not for others. For others, it opens Word but does not populate any data and errors out. I'm newer to this so no clue why this works for me, but not others and I'd like to understand for future coding.

Thanks for taking a look.

Here is the part of code that is giving the error on "wrdApp.Selection.Paste" line

```
Sheets("Sch1A").Range("Print_Area").Copy

    With objWord

        wrdApp.Selection.Paste
```

This is not the full set of code, but this is the piece that contains the error and related variables.

```
'Below is where the embedded word doc opens and pastes in the code
Dim wrdApp As Word.Application

Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

Dim sh As Shape

Dim objWord As Object, objNewDoc As Object ''Word.Document

'Dim objOLE As New OLEObject

Dim objOLE As OLEObject

Dim wSystem As Worksheet

Dim cell As Range

 

Set wSystem = Worksheets("Schedule variables")

''The shape holding the object from 'Create from file'

''Object 2 is the name of the shape

Set sh = wSystem.Shapes("PageBreak")

''The OLE Object contained

Set objOLE = sh.OLEFormat.Object

'Instead of activating in-place, open in Word

objOLE.Verb xlOpen

Set objWord = objOLE.Object 'The Word document

 

Dim objUndo As Object 'Word.UndoRecord

'Be able to undo all editing performed by the macro in one step

Set objUndo = objWord.Application.UndoRecord

objUndo.StartCustomRecord "Edit In Word"

   

Sheets("Sch1A").Range("Print_Area").Copy

    With objWord

        wrdApp.Selection.Paste

        wrdApp.Selection.InsertBreak

    End With

   

'Add footer

wrdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = wdSeekCurrentPageFooter

wrdApp.Selection.Font.Size = 7

wrdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

wrdApp.Selection.TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule variables").Range("S1").Text

'wrdApp.Selection.TypeText vbTab & vbTab & "             " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule variables").Range("O5").Text

wrdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

wrdApp.Selection.Font.Size = 7

wrdApp.Selection.TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule variables").Range("S2").Text

wrdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

wrdApp.Selection.Font.Size = 7

wrdApp.Selection.TypeText ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule variables").Range("S3").Text

'wrdApp.Selection.TypeParagraph

'wrdApp.Selection.TypeText vbTab & vbTab & "             " & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Schedule variables").Range("O7").Text

wrdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.SeekView = 0

 

Sheets("Sch1B").Range("Print_Area").Copy

    With objWord

        wrdApp.Selection.Paste

        wrdApp.Selection.InsertBreak

    End With

   

Sheets("Sch2").Range("Print_Area").Copy

    With objWord

        wrdApp.Selection.Paste

        wrdApp.Selection.InsertBreak

    End With

   

Sheets("Sch3").Range("Print_Area").Copy

    With objWord

        wrdApp.Selection.Paste

        wrdApp.Selection.InsertBreak

    End With

   

'Password protect and only allow track changes in Word document

'wrdApp.ActiveDocument.Protect password:="wildcard", NoReset:=False, Type:= _

'       wdAllowOnlyComments, UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=False

 

'Save as client name to same path the Excel file is saved and undo everything for the embedded document to be clean

With objWord

    objWord.SaveAs2 ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & Sheets("Schedule variables").Range("S1").Value

    objUndo.EndCustomRecord

    Set objUndo = Nothing

    objWord.Undo

    .Application.Quit False

End With

 

Set objWord = Nothing

Set WordDoc = Nothing

Set WordApp = Nothing

 

'TURN BACK ON IN FINAL CODE

'Sheets("Schedule variables").Visible = False

'Sheets("Sch1A").Visible = False

'Sheets("Sch1B").Visible = False

'Sheets("Sch2").Visible = False

'Sheets("Sch3").Visible = False

'ThisWorkbook.Protect password:="wildcard"

 

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

 

'Call EmailFile

 

'Show message box where schedule was saved down

MsgBox Sheets("Schedule variables").Range("S1").Text & " has been saved in this folder " & ActiveWorkbook.Path

 

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: That code is quite confusing, are you trying to create a new Word document or are you working with an existing Word document that's embedded on an Excel worksheet?

Comment: I'd have to check to be sure, but I don't think the section `'Instead of activating in-place, open in Word; objOLE.Verb xlOpen` will specifically or always be guaranteed to open that OLE object in Word. That part is a bit suspect here to me at least.

Comment: Also, the statements inside the blocks that use `With objWord` have nothing to do with `objWord` at all. So I wouldn't expect anything related to the OLE object to be pasted.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and sorry for the sloppy code. The error is Run-time'91' Object variable or With block variable not set. I am trying to open the Word doc which has headers in it from the same Excel file. I see what you're saying about the objWord, but still not understanding why this runs fine for me. Hope this helps.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to paste into the Word doc?  Just reading the code, it looks like you want the cells from the printable area of a worksheet pasted into the Word doc. This has nothing to do with an OLE object. The implication is that there is an OLE object attached to the `.Shapes("PageBreak")`. So the bigger question is what is the OLE object and how does it relate to what you want pasted? It's very unclear.

Comment: I am trying to paste the print areas of the 4 tabs in the code to the embedded Word doc.

Comment: You want to paste those areas as images (basically a screen-shot clip of that area) or what the final, actual printed page would look like to the Word doc?

Comment: They need to be pasted so formatting carries over and can be edited.

Answer (score 1):

The quick solution to your problem lies in how you're pasting the range to Word. OLE objects are not applicable to the process.

The example below should give you a template to apply to your solution.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyPrintAreasToWord()
    Dim wordApp As Word.Application
    Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
    Set wordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    wordApp.Visible = True
    
    Set wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1
    
    Dim currentPrintArea As Range
    Set currentPrintArea = ws.Range("Print_Area")
    currentPrintArea.Copy
    
    wordDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable LinkedToExcel:=False, _
                                                WordFormatting:=False, _
                                                RTF:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I will test this sometime this week to see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

I'm posting a second answer here because in the course of digging into the solution, I encountered a question that I believe the OP's question and code does not really address. And that is: *what is the real printable area of a worksheet, and what happens if the range is larger than a single page?*

My other answer (hopefully) directly and succinctly addresses the OP's question. This answer tries to address this larger question, just in case in comes up.

The function below is not incorporated into the OP's code, nor into my other answer. But I'm providing it here for the community.

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestGettingPrintRanges()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet2
    
    Dim thisPage As Range
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To (ws.HPageBreaks.Count + 1)
        Set thisPage = GetPrintPageRange(i, ws)
        Debug.Print "Page " & i; " print area = " & thisPage.Address
    Next i
End Sub

Function GetPrintPageRange(ByVal pageNumber As Long, ByRef ws As Worksheet) As Range
    '--- returns the range defined by the worksheet print area, as assigned
    '    to the given page number
    '------ NOTE: currently assumes that VPageBreaks.Count = 0
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim fullPrintArea As Range
    Set fullPrintArea = ws.Range("Print_Area")
    If fullPrintArea Is Nothing Then
        Debug.Print "ERROR: print area has not been set!"
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim upperLeftCell As Range
    Set upperLeftCell = fullPrintArea.Resize(1, 1)
    
    '--- strangeness working with HPageBreaks.Count is that there *MIGHT* be one
    '    more page than the count indicates.
    Dim thisPageArea As Range
    If (pageNumber > (ws.HPageBreaks.Count + 1)) Then
        Debug.Print "ERROR: page number " & pageNumber & _
                    " is greater than page count (" & ws.HPageBreaks.Count & ")"
        Set GetPrintPageRange = Nothing
    ElseIf (pageNumber <= ws.HPageBreaks.Count) Then
        With ws
            Dim lowerRightCell As Range
            Set lowerRightCell = fullPrintArea.Resize(1, 1).Offset(fullPrintArea.Rows.Count - 1, _
                                                                   fullPrintArea.Columns.Count - 1)
            
            Dim columnsInThisPage As Long
            columnsInThisPage = lowerRightCell.Column - upperLeftCell.Column + 1
            
            Dim rowsInThisPage As Long
            If (pageNumber = 1) Then
                rowsInThisPage = .HPageBreaks(pageNumber).Location.Row - upperLeftCell.Row
                Set thisPageArea = upperLeftCell.Resize(rowsInThisPage, columnsInThisPage)
            Else
                Dim prevPageBreakCell As Range
                Set prevPageBreakCell = ws.HPageBreaks(pageNumber - 1).Location
                rowsInThisPage = .HPageBreaks(pageNumber).Location.Row - prevPageBreakCell.Row
                Set thisPageArea = .Range(.Cells(.HPageBreaks(pageNumber - 1).Location.Row, upperLeftCell.Column), _
                                          .Cells(.HPageBreaks(pageNumber).Location.Row - 1, _
                                                 upperLeftCell.Column + columnsInThisPage - 1))
            End If
        End With
    Else
        '--- this is the special case to check if there is another print area
        '    beyond the given page count or if the HPageBreaks.Count is zero,
        '    we may still have a "Print_Area" range that's less than a full page
        If (ws.HPageBreaks.Count = 0) Then
            Set thisPageArea = ws.Range("Print_Area")
        Else
            Dim lastPageNumber As Long
            lastPageNumber = ws.HPageBreaks.Count
            
            Dim lastPageCell As Range
            Set lastPageCell = ws.HPageBreaks(lastPageNumber).Location
            If (fullPrintArea.Rows(fullPrintArea.Rows.Count).Row - lastPageCell.Row) > 0 Then
                '--- we have an extra page here, so...
                Set thisPageArea = ws.Range(ws.Cells(lastPageCell.Row, upperLeftCell.Column), _
                                            ws.Cells(fullPrintArea.Rows(fullPrintArea.Rows.Count).Row, _
                                                     fullPrintArea.Columns(fullPrintArea.Columns.Count).Column))
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Set GetPrintPageRange = thisPageArea
End Function
```